# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'directions'

Tags: python

### I've updated the code so that it appears exactly as it does on my machine.

I've been developing a simple Python text adventure engine, and I've run into a problem. If you can solve my problem or have a more efficient way to code/structure a method or class, please tell me! I'm new to this sort of thing, and any advice would be great! Also, formatting might not be up to par, but hey, I tried!

Okay, so my project has two modules, titled `Game` and `Map`. The first module, `Game`, "parses" user input and change the room the player is standing in. The second module, `Map`, outlines a `Room` class that contains a constructor and some functions relating to directions, exits, etc. I hadn't yet solved moving into a non-existing room, and I'm sure that my code is fairly terrible, but here it is:

---

Error message

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
You are in a small, cramped space.
It is cold and dark. There is a door to your North.

 > Go North

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Documents\Python\Game.py", line 25, in <module>
    currentRoom = currentRoom.directions[0]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'directions'
>>>
```

---

`Game` module

```
# It is the main engine for PyrPG
import Map

currentRoom = Map.currentRoom

def updateGame():
    currentRoom.displayName()
def invalidCommand():
    print("Invalid command. Try again.")
while(True):
    updateGame()
    command = input(" > ")
    print()
    
    partition = command.partition("Go" or "go" or "Take" or "take")
    action = partition[1]
    item = partition[2]
    if(action == "Go" or "go"):
        if(item == " North" or " north"):
            currentRoom = currentRoom.directions[0]
        if(item == " East" or " east"):
            currentRoom = currentRoom.directions[0]
        if(item == " South" or " south"):
            currentRoom = currentRoom.directions[0]
        if(item == " West" or " west"):
            currentRoom = currentRoom.directions[0]
    else:
        print("Invalid command.")
```

---

`Map` module

```
# It handles rooms.
class Room:
    rmCount = 0
    directions = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        # Name and description
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

        # Directions
        self.directions = None
        self.canNorth = False
        self.canWest = False
        self.canSouth = False
        self.canEast = False

        # Increase room count
        Room.rmCount += 1
        
    def displayName(self):
        print(self.name)
        print(self.description)
        print()

    def displayDirections(self, directions):
        # Check directions, modify booleans
        if(self.directions[0] != 0):
            self.canNorth = True
            gNorth = "North"
        else:
            gNorth = ""
        if(self.directions[1] != 0):
            self.canEast = True
            gEast = "East"
        else:
            gEast = ""
        if(self.directions[2] != 0):
            self.canSouth = True
            gSouth = "South"
        else:
            gSouth = ""
        if(self.directions[3] != 0):
            self.canWest = True
            gWest = "West"
        else:
            gWest = ""

        print("Directions:", gNorth, gEast, gSouth, gWest)

    def setDirections(self, directions):
        self.directions = directions

    def displayInfo():
        displayName()
        displayDirections()

introRoom = Room("Welcome to the Cave.", "To start the game, type \"Go North\"")
storageCloset = Room("You are in a small, cramped space.", "It is cold and dark. There is a door to your North.")
mainOffice = Room("the main office.", "It is cold and empty.")
currentRoom = storageCloset

introRoom.setDirections([storageCloset, 0, 0, 0])
storageCloset.setDirections([mainOffice, 0, 0, 0])
mainOffice.setDirections([0, 0, storageCloset, 0])
```

---

Again, if you see something hideous, please tell me! This is the first project I have written on my own without any instruction. Thanks!

Comment: at some point, you have assigned an `int` value to currentRoom.

Comment: @HughBothwell I figured as much, but I can't tell where I assigned that `int` value!

Comment: I believe the command `currentRoom = Map.currentRoom` in your main module is incorrect.  Change it too `currentRoom = Map.Room(name, description)`.

Comment: @Remolten Changed it and got `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'description'`

Comment: Instead of setting `currentRoom = storageCloset` in your `Map` module.  You need too make the room by doing `currentRoom = Map.Room(name, description)` and filling in arguments you want.  Put in whatever your `storageCloset` arguments are and try it.

Comment: Also where do you define introRoom?

Comment: @user3387584 I removed introRoom from the preview in the `Map` module, will add it back to clear things up.

Comment: @Remolten `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two major bugs I can see, a bunch of not-bug-but-still-bad bits, and probably more problems I haven't noticed. Here are the major bugs.

#### Problem 1:

```
partition = command.partition("Go" or "go" or "Take" or "take")
```

`or` doesn't work like that. This won't try `command.partition` with four possible arguments. Instead,

```
"Go" or "go" or "Take" or "take"
```

evaluates to `"Go"`, and the call becomes

```
partition = command.partition("Go")
```

This problem occurs every single place you use `or`. The biggest impact is when it occurs in an `if` condition, where it causes the `if` to always be taken.

#### Problem 2:

```
currentRoom = currentRoom.directions[0]
```

There are 4 lines that all say this. Each one picks the same `directions` element. They shouldn't be doing that; they should all go in a different direction.

Comment: @user3387584: Indeed. That should actually `NameError` in the `Map` module, so the actual code probably looks different from what we've been shown.

Comment: I've updated the code. Would you recommend I handle using `partition` in a different way?

Comment: @user3188407: Just `split` the string. `command.split()` will give you a list where the first element is `'Go'` or whatever first word the user used and the second element is `'North'`, `'East'`, or whatever direction the user input.

Comment: Is the use of `or` acceptable with that? Right now in my modded version, I have a `partition1` and a `partition2`, each with their own `action` and `item` :P

Comment: @user3188407: I don't know what you're trying to say your modded version looks like. In general, `x or y` should only be used to test whether at least one of `x` or `y` is true. It's a boolean logic operator; it doesn't do most of the things you might think it would if you read it like the English conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here...

```
if(item == " North" or " north"):
```

This is an incorrect way to test the condition.

What you need to do is

```
if (item == " North") or (item == " north"):
```

Look at other places too where you are checking a condition using "or".

Answer (score 0):

I've modified `Map.py` to be a bit more flexible:

```
class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key.lower())
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return dict.__setitem__(self, key.lower(), value)

# room index
all_rooms = CaseInsensitiveDict()

class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        all_rooms[name] = self   # add to index
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.dirs = CaseInsensitiveDict()

    def add_dir(self, dir, room_name):
        self.dirs[dir] = all_rooms[room_name]

    @property
    def directions(self):
        return "From here you can go: " + ", ".join(sorted(self.dirs.keys())) + "\n"

    def go(self, dir):
        try:
            next_room = self.dirs[dir]
            print(next_room)
            return next_room
        except KeyError:
            print("You can't go {} from here.\n".format(dir))
            return self

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            self.name + "\n" +
            self.description + "\n"
        )

def make_link(dir_a, room_a, dir_b, room_b):
    if dir_b:
        all_rooms[room_a].add_dir(dir_b, room_b)
    if dir_a:
        all_rooms[room_b].add_dir(dir_a, room_a)
```

which you can then use like

```
Room("Small closet", "You are in a small, cramped space. It is cold and dark. There is a door to your North.")
Room("Dusty office", "This must be the main office. It is still cold and dark. There is a door marked 'Supplies' to the South, and a set of double doors to the East.")
Room("Foyer", "Blah blah")

make_link("North", "Dusty office", "South", "Small closet")
make_link("East", "Foyer", "West", "Dusty office")

here = all_rooms["small closet"]
```

then

```
>>> print(here)
Small closet
You are in a small, cramped space. It is cold and dark. There is a door to your North.

>>> here = here.go("north")
Dusty office
This must be the main office. It is still cold and dark. There is a door marked 'Supplies' to the South, and a set of double doors to the East.

>>> here = here.go("north")
You can't go north from here.

>>> print(here.directions)
From here you can go: east, south

>>> here = here.go("east")
Foyer
Blah blah
```

Comment: Wow. That's a little advanced, haha. However, I can follow it pretty well. Thank you!